# Parsing nested json array value in php

Tags: javascript, php, json, cordova

I am trying to parse the data from the following json

```
{
"id":"1",
"rawId":"1",
"displayName":"Distress Number",
"name":{"familyName":"Number","formatted":"Distress Number","givenName":"Distress"},
"nickname":null,
"phoneNumbers":[{"type":"other","value":"112","id":"2","pref":false}],
"emails":[{"type":"other","value":"blessan004@gmail.com","id":"19","pref":false}],
"addresses":null,
"ims":null,"organizations":null,
"birthday":null,
"note":"","photos":null,
"categories":null,
"urls":null
}
```

I want to insert the `displaName`,`phoneNumbers` and `emails` to database table but its failed
Here is my php

```
$contact=json_decode($json,true){
    foreach($contact as $con){

         $num=$con['phoneNumbers']['value'];
        $name=$con['displayName'];
        $email=$con['emails']['value'];
         //function to dbinsert 
        insertToDb($num,$name,$email);
     }
```

But it returns `illegal offset warning`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425700/parsing-nested-json-to-retrieve-nested-array-values

Comment: I don't understand how your data are structured. Is there only one record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this , phoneNumbers and emails are again the json array you need to parse

```
        $contact=json_decode($json,true);
        foreach($contact as $con){
        $num=$con['phoneNumbers'][0]['value'];
        $name=$con['displayName'];
        $email=$con['emails'][0]['value'];
     //function to dbinsert 
        insertToDb($num,$name,$email);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `json_decode` in the wrong way. Try to do like this:

```
$contact=json_decode($json,true);
foreach($contact as $con) {

    $num=$con['phoneNumbers']['value'];
    $name=$con['displayName'];
    $email=$con['emails']['value'];

    insertToDb($num,$name,$email);
 }
```

Comment: I think this `json_decode($json,true) {` is incorrect. The bracket in particular

Comment: i wiil get `displayName` but not `$num` and `$name`